# How do I take control away from a cell on a grid when the cell is using a RepositoryTextEditor

Tags: c#, xtragrid

I have a Repository Text editor for my xtragrid to handle percentages that the user can enter.  The problem seems to be that the repository text editor seems to cause the focus to behave strangely.

When I enter the value and press Enter, the cell will leave the editor open until I click on another cell in the table.  Meanwhile, the table focus will jump to the top left cell (leaving the recently edited cell's editor open).

When this happens, arrow keys will navigate the table's focus, but other keys will type into the editor.

I've tried calling the CloseEditor event on the gridview in the repository editor's Validating event as well as the Cell Value changed event, but with no results.  Has this happened to anybody else?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the gridview is recreated but the table is not.  My problem was that this edit would cause me to reinitialize the table.  When doing this, the table grid selected starts at the top left as per default, but since the grid cells are essentially new, the close event never gets called before the gridview is recreated, leaving it in an odd state.

I resolved this by not creating a gridview and assigning it to the grid under these circumstances and recreating the entire table (not just the gridview) when a table change is needed.